# how to copy two files by SCP in expect script

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

please advice why

```
     spawn  scp  $FILE1   $FILE2  $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

in my expect script copy only FILE1 and not copy FILE2 ?

I try to to transfer both files by scp  as

```
 scp file1.csv file2.crt 192.8.200.1:/tmp
```

without expect  and they transferred successfully to /tmp

so why VIA expect the only file that copied is **FILE1** ??

what wrong in my syntax ?

---

example of my expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set FILE1  file1.csv
set FILE2  file2.crt

set multiPrompt {[#>$]}

spawn  scp  $FILE1   $FILE2  $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
expect {
    ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

    word:  {send $PASS\r}
}
```

I also try this:

```
 spawn  scp  "$FILE1   $FILE2"   $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

OR

```
 spawn  scp  '$FILE1   $FILE2'   $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

but I get the same problem

PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149936/4667 for comments and answers

Comment: Have you tried doing `exp_internal 1` so you can see exactly what Expect is doing and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround it by using array and foreach in expect script, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set files { file1.csv file2.crt }

foreach file $files {

puts "Let's scp $file"
send "scp $file $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp"

}
```